# Programatically set delegate for UICollectionView is not working

Tags: ios, delegates, datasource, collectionview

I have a viewcontroller A controlling a large view. On that view I have a subview C of type `CollectionView`.

I want a separate class C_Manager to handle the delegate and dataSource functionality for the C subview

I have the following

in A's `viewDidLoad`

```
cManager = [[C_Manager alloc] init];

cManager.collection = C;
self.C.delegate = cManager;
self.C.dataSource = cManager;
```

in C_Manager.h I have

```
@interface C_Manager : NSObject <UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

and in C_Manager.m I have :

```
// all the functions for the dataSource plus 

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
}
```

I never reach the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Interestingly, I do reach the functions for the dataSource protocol, and if I disable the line which sets it - I dont reach it anymore...

I checked the view C in the xib - the `"User Interraction Enabled"` is checked ...

What is wrong ?

Comment: Check the `allowsSelection` property of the collection view.  Also check whether your delegate implements `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:` and if so, whether it returns `YES`.

Comment: Also, in `-[C_manager collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]`, add an `NSLog` that prints the collection view's data source and delegate.  Are they still set to the same object by that time?

Comment: thanks. set `allowSelection` - no help. printed the `%@` view.delegate in the `numberOfItemsInSelection` - gives me the exact instance of the cManager ... Probably something is wrong with the touches over this part of the view ...

Comment: btw : I have a scroll in the collectionview - it works just fine ...

Comment: FOUND IT : i had a touchesBegin implemented in the class of my CELL and it was intercepting the taps

Comment: you may want to write that in an answer, so people don't think this is unanswered.

Comment: Related ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042908/for-uicollectionview-set-the-controller-in-storyboard